# Unable to arrange divs properly

Tags: html, css

I can't get my divs to layout properly.  I'm trying to have a top bar which is 200px high and takes up 100% width.  Under that is a left bar which is 200px wide and 100% height then a right bar which will take up the rest of the space.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>my view</title>

    <style>
        #tb {
            background-color:#cc0000;
            height:200px;
            width:100%;
            position:relative;
        }

        #lb {
            background-color:#00cc00;
            width:200px;
            height:100%;
            float:left;
        }

        #rb {
            background-color:#cccccc;
            height:100%;
            float:right;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="page" style="width:100%;height:100%">

    <div id="tb" style=""/>
    <div id="lb"/>
    <div id="rb" style=""/>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks even worse when I put some content in the divs:

```
<div id="tb" style="">test</div>
    <div id="lb">test</div>
    <div id="rb" style="">test</div>
```

Comment: For reference, `<div id="lb"/>` is not valid HTML.  Elements that require closing tags can not be self-closing.  (Self-closing tags are an XML thing, and *might* be valid in XHTML...but not in HTML.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height: 100%` or `width: 100%` are not the rest of the size, but the overall size of the parent, ie the entire document.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/oswaldoacauan/3yxkn/) is an example of what you want using a table.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/oswaldoacauan/zuzXB/1/) is an exemple with divs.

Comment: Should I use tables instead of divs?  I thought that using a table for anything but tabular data was bad design.

Comment: I'm trying to develop a solution with divs for you :)

Comment: tables are much easier (imo) to work it when it comes to a design like yours, but yeah, they are usually avoided nowadays

Comment: @RockyTriton, no you should not use a table for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I guess I will just have to do some javascript to  resize the divs to make them take up the full space of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want elastic layout then give some minimum and maximum width to your wrapper div #page, then top header of your design will accomodate according to the width of parent div #page. This is not a good idea to give height to  your wrapper div but you can use min-height.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set divs to self close btw -> here's an example for you http://jsfiddle.net/QHTeS/2/

```
#tb {
    background-color:#cc0000;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}

#lb{
    float: left;
    background:red;
    width:200px;

}

#rb{

    background:green
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Using `<div>`s and CSS (i.e. not tables) - layout just doesn't work this way. (Also, as a commenter pointed out, some of the HTML is not valid).

Floated elements height will mainly be dependent on the content within them. You have fallen into the trap of thinking that the 'height' CSS declaration means what you would expect it to mean. ("Unlearn what you have learned")

You will have to accept that with normal HTML/CSS flow, that the two lower divs will be differing heights. You can, however, *fake* the effect you're after with something like [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

Answer (score -1):

first div is pair element so `<div></div>`

fluid layout with div is little bit tricky.

this should work for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>my view</title>

<style>
    html, body {height: 100%;}
    #tb {
        background-color:#cc0000;
        height:200px;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
    }

    #lb {
        background-color:#00cc00;
        width:200px;
        height:100%;
        float:left;
        margin-left: -200px;
    }

    #rb {
        background-color:#cccccc;
        height:100%;
        float:right;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #content {
        margin-left: 200px; 
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="page" style="width:100%;height:100%">

    <div id="tb" style=""></div>
    <div id="content">
       <div id="lb"></div>
       <div id="rb" style=""></div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

To fill exact portions of the page you will need to use absolute positioning instead, since the percent width/height relate to the size of the parent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>my view</title>

    <style>
        #tb {
            background-color:#cc0000;
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            bottom:200px;
            right:0px;
        }

        #lb {
            background-color:#00cc00;
            position:absolute;
            top:200px;
            left:0px;
            bottom:0px;
            right:200px;
        }

        #rb {
            background-color:#cccccc;
            position:absolute;
            top: 200px;
            left:200px;
            bottom:0px;
            right:0px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="page" style="width:100%;height:100%">

    <div id="tb" style=""></div>
    <div id="lb"></div>
    <div id="rb" style=""></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```